# Pyqt check signal is being emitted

Tags: python, pyqt, signals, receiver, emit

In my `pyqt` application I emit a different signal once particulare keys are pressed, like:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    """
    keyboard events that enable actions

    . starts single correction mode
    m stats multiple correction mode
    \ starts zeroing
    ESC stops any action
    s starts suggestion mode
    n starts neutralisation mode
    :param event: keyboard event
    :return:
    """

    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Period:
        logger.log(5, "{} has been pressed".format(event.text()))
        self.single_correction.emit() # single correction mode
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_M:
        logger.log(5, "{} has been pressed".format(event.text()))
        self.multiple_correction.emit()  # multiple correction mode
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_S: # m key
        logger.log(5, " {} has been pressed".format(event.text()))
        self.suggested_correction.emit() # suggestion mode
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_N:
        logger.log(5, " {} has been pressed".format(event.text()))
        self.neutralisation_mode.emit() # neutralisation mode
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Backslash:
        logger.log(5, " {} has been pressed".format(event.text()))
        self.zeroing.emit() # zeroing
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
        logger.log(5, " {} has been pressed".format(event.text()))
        self.unzeroing.emit() # unzeroring
    if event.key() == Qt.Key_Escape: # esc key
        logger.log(5, " {} has been pressed".format(event.text()))
        self.stop.emit() #stop
```

then I have another function that connects each signal to an action

```
def create_connections(self):
    """
    function that handles connections
    when a signal is emitted it connects to the appropriate action
    :return:
    """
    self.lineEdit_mancorr.signal_evoke_kb.connect(self.show_kb)
    self.single_correction.connect(self.singlecorrection)
    self.multiple_correction.connect(self.multiplecorrection)
    self.zeroing.connect(self.zeroingcorrection)
    self.unzeroing.connect(self.unzeroingcorrection)
    self.stop.connect(self.stopcorrection)
    self.neutralisation_mode.connect(self.neutralisatecorrections)
    self.suggested_correction.connect(self.suggestcorrection)
```

I would like to understand if there is a way to check with an if statement if a signal has been emitted or not.

Comment: example: if "m" key is pressed then "multiple_correction" signal is emitted.

Comment: I asked in which cases the signal **is not emitted**

Comment: when you press keys that are not listed in the keyevent function

Comment: Do you realize what you require? 99.9999999999999999999999999999999999% of the time the signal is not emitted. What you require is impossible, the trivial way is to enter some `else` where the signal is emitted: `if event.key() == Qt.Key_Backslash: self.zeroing.emit() else: print("not emitted")` . Maybe you have an XY problem, what is your final goal?

Comment: example: if "." key is pressed then "singlecorrection" signal is
emitted. When this signal is emitted the "singlecorrection" function
is called.

once inside this function I would like the app to wait until another action by the user is performed (and consequently another signal is emitted)

and then carry on.

this is why I was asking for a way to check if the signal as been emitted.

Comment: Could you give a more real example? Now I'm more confident that you have a XY problem

Comment: the key event triggers the emission of a signal. then I need to perform actions and the user is required to give input from keyboard (i.e. write something on a lineedit) and using mouse (clicking areas of a signal plotted in a canvas) this action will then will be used by the function "singlecorrection" that was waiting. and after that i should go again idle waiting for another key event to repeat. this is what the requirement say.

Comment: I do not want the requirement because it is abstract. What I have asked you is a real example, for example, what type of widget belongs to the keyPressEvent ?, after pressing the "." What should be done? After which key must be pressed or signal must be issued to continue the work? What work should be done? Your initial question is confusing and your possible solution is incorrect since it is impossible to implement it

Comment: [cont] so I recommend you rewrite your question indicating a real and practical problem for example: *if you press  **"."** a dialogue will open, in the dialog there is a qlineedit with a button, after writing something in the QLineEdit the button is pressed and the dialog is closed, then the information of the qlineedit is used to obtain another text that will be displayed in a QLabel* , that's what I mean with real problem

Comment: I fixed it redefining correctly the logic, thanks